# Creating multiple objects of the same type with user input?

Tags: java, class, oop, object, inheritance

I'm trying to make a program with three class files, two Objects files and one Main that accesses both and runs operations. The first object file creates objects with one parameter, and then assigns attributes to itself based on said parameter, for example.

```
public class People {
    private int height, weight;
    private String specificPerson;
    public People(String  person){
        this.specificPerson = person;
        this.height = person.length * 12;
        this.weight = person.length * 40;
    }

    public int getHeight(){return height;}

    public int getWeight() {return weight;}
}
```

These objects are then stored within the array of another object which has a capacity and an array:

```
public class peopleIndexer {
    private int pcapacity, size;
    private String[] peopleArray;        
    public peopleIndexer(int capacity){
        this.pcapacity = capacity;
        this.peopleArray = new String [capacity];
    }

    public int getCapacity(){
        return pcapacity;
    }

    public int[] getInfo(String person){
        int[] getInfo = new int[2];
        int found = Arrays.binarySearch(peopleArray,person);
        getInfo[0] = ?.getHeight();
        getInfo[1] = ?.getWeight();//I dont know the object name yet so I put "?" for I am not sure
        System.out.println("Person" + person + "is " + getInfo[0] + "tall and " + getInfo[1] + " pounds.");
    }

}
```

What I need to know is how to allow the user to make multiple people in the list with input that I can then allow them to retrieve later, for example:

```
String user_input;
People user_input = new People("user_input");
```

So that if the users input were to be jack, ryan, and nick, I would have three objects placed in the peopleIndexer as such:

```
People jack = new People(jack);
People ryan = new People(ryan);
People nick = new People(nick);
```

Comment: `Would you like to create a new Person? Y or N`. `How many people do you want to create?` <- Use the number from here to create a loop that will ask to enter information about a person N number of times.

Comment: Y, I need to make new people each time, and the amount of people or capacity is determined by user at the beginning of the program.

Answer (score 0):

Your People constructor takes only one argument and creates a People object..You do not have setters for some of your private variables in the peopleIndexer class, so best to have your main method as part of the peopleIndexer class.

Your "length" attribute in the People constructor is not initialized or declared anywhere, so let's assume it's not there. You must change your "private String[] peopleArray;" to be "private People[] peopleArray;" in order to have people in the array.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int capacity;
    int peopleCount = 0; //used to keep track of people we have in our array
    String person = "";
    
    // get the capacity from the user
    System.out.println("Enter the number of people you want to capture: ");
    capacity = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
    
    //create peopleIndexer object using the given capacity
    peopleIndexer pIndexer = new peopleIndexer(capacity); 

    while(peopleCount < capacity){

          //prompt the user for the "People" name, this is the only attibute we need according to your constructor.
          System.out.println("Enter person "+(peopleCount + 1)+" name: ");
          person = input.nextLine();
          
          //add a new person into the array
          peopleArray[peopleCount] = new People(person);

          //increase the number of people captured
          peopleCount += 1;
    }
}
```